# How to group and select unique values in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I've asked this question on the SharePoint StackExchange w/ no luck

I have a CSV file with one column, SharePoint Site URLs, many of which are duplicates

```
Column Title
Site C URL
Site A URL
Site B URL
Site C URL
Site C URL
Site A URL
```

How can I retrieve the rows so the I only have unique sites:

```
Site A URL 
Site B URL 
Site C URL
```

I've tried:

```
$CSVLocation = 'C:\data\data.csv'
$siteURLs = Import-CSV -Path $CSVLocation 
$siteURLs | Group-Object -Property 'Column Title' | Select-Object -Unique
```

Comment: `Group-Object` by default outputs three properties: Count, Name, Group. Since you are grouping by 'Column Title', those values will appear under `Name`. So if you only want to see that data, you need to select `Name`. `$siteURLs | Group-Object -Property 'Column Title' | Select-Object Name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can approach this problem several ways. One simple way is to use `Sort-Object` provided you only have the one column.

```
$siteURLs | Sort-Object 'Column Title' -Unique
```

You can also use `Group-Object`. `Group-Object` by default outputs three properties: `Count`, `Name`, `Group`. Since you are grouping by `Column Title`, those values will appear under `Name`. So if you only want to see that data, you need to select `Name`.

```
$siteURLs | Group-Object -Property 'Column Title' | Select-Object Name
```

Comment: Thanks for this I'm still having a bit of an issue.  After trying both approaches I'm getting the same result:
foreach($site in $siteURLs){ Write-Host $site }  The result is:
@{Column Title=http://intranet.xxx.com/sites/Ops/ss/KnowledgeLibrary}
Ultimately, I need to Get-List -web $site.  Thanks again

Comment: Sorry if what I'm asking isn't clear.   What I'm getting is:
@{Column Title=intranet.xxx.com/sites/Ops/ss/KnowledgeLibrary} 
What I want is the URL.  Thanks!!

Comment: If you only want the value, then you can use `$site.'Column Title'`. You should not use `Write-Host` to output objects with properties. It will stringify the object and format like you are seeing.

Comment: Thank You.  That was very tricky.  Particularly the Write-Host part!